# Struggling with GREP commands, removing decimal point correctly

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line

I've written the shell command below to output the CPU's clock speed as an integer:

```
grep -m 1 'cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'
```

OUTPUT:

```
900
063
```

This is because the exact clock speed is 900.063. Essentially, I want the command to return the 900 part but not the part after the decimal (.063).

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is appending `| head -n 1` on the end not acceptable? This will give you the first line of output.

Answer (score 3):

This might be easier done in awk:

```
awk -F: '/cpu MHz/ {print int($2); exit}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

- `-F:` - split on `:`
- `/cpu MHz/` on lines matching `cpu MHz`, do:

  - `{print int($2); exit}'` - convert second field to integer, print it and exit (so we get only the first match)

Comment: Or GNU `awk -F[:.] '/cpu MHz/{print $2; exit}`

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. Here's another one:

```
grep -m 1 'cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo | cut -f2 -d: | cut -f1 -d.
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is Try

command

```
sed -n '/cpu MHz/s/.*://p' /proc/cpuinfo | sed "s/\..*//g"
```

Awk method

```
awk  -F ":" '/cpu MHz/{gsub(/\..*/,"",$NF);print $NF}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'cpu MHz')
m=open('/proc/cpuinfo','r')
for i in m:
    if re.search(k,i):
        print i.split(":")[-1].split(".")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed is

```
grep -m 1 'cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo | sed -r 's/^(.*? )([0-9]+)(\..+)$/\2/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`:

```
grep -om1 'cpu MHz[^.]*' /proc/cpuinfo | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*'
```

Get the line without the dot and the following characters, then `grep` for the digits.

If your `grep` supports Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE):

```
grep -oPm1 'cpu MHz.* \K[[:digit:]]+' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Everything before the `\K` is matched as usual, but not included in the output (variable length lookbehind).

Answer (score 0):

Adding some anchor (like the leading space) should give you what you need:

```
$ grep -m 1 '^cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo | grep -oE ' [0-9]+'
 900
```

If the leading space on the output is a problem, you can anchor on the dot:

```
$ grep -m 1 '^cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.'
900.
```

If both space and dot are a problem, we need to step up to a higher level regex, PCRE:

```
$ grep -oPm 1  '^cpu MHz.* \K[0-9]+(?=\.)' /proc/cpuinfo
900
```

Which checks both the space and dot, but prints neither.

An equivalent with sed may be:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^cpu MHz.* ([0-9]+)\..*$/\1/p;T;q' /proc/cpuinfo
900
```

And with awk:

```
$ awk -F '[ .]' '/^cpu MHz/{print $3;exit}' /proc/cpuinfo
900
```

Answer (score 0):

avg:

`awk '/cpu MHz/{SUM+=$NF; LINE+=+1}END {printf "%0d" ,SUM/LINE}' /proc/cpuinfo`